# Установка пакетов python c помощью pip на OpenShift

Tags: python, openshift, pip, scrapy

Нужно установить `scrapy` и `scrapyd`.
При установке получаю ошибку:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna'
```

Это вообще возможно, или можно пользоваться тем, что есть в дистрибутиве?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
$ rhc ssh <app_name>
$ pip install scrapy scrapyd
```

Или пропиши эти пакеты в requirements.txt

```
scrapy==1.1.2
scrapyd==1.1.0
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую и отпишусь.

Comment: Останавливается на "Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml", висит а потом сессия завершается.